# Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails, intentando agregar clave foránea en la misma tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero hacer una `FOREING KEY` a una misma tabla, pero no me funciona, me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`empresa.#sql-2678_4, CONSTRAINT #sql-2678_4_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (ID_Jefe) REFERENCES empleados (ID_Empleado) ON DELETE CASCADE`)

Éste es mi código hasta el momento de la tabla a la que se lo quiero poner:

```
CREATE TABLE Empleados(
ID_Empleado VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Nombre VARCHAR(30),
Sexo CHAR(30),
Nacimiento DATE,
Incorporacion DATE,
Salario FLOAT(20),
Comision FLOAT(20),
Cargo VARCHAR(30),
ID_Jefe VARCHAR(30),
Codigo_de_departamento VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY(ID_Empleado),
FOREIGN KEY (Codigo_de_departamento) REFERENCES Departamento (Codigo_de_departamento)
ON DELETE SET NULL
ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

ALTER TABLE Empleados
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ID_Jefe) REFERENCES Empleados (ID_Empleado)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: ¿ Que error te da ? Y por cierto, "on delete cascade" no parece lo más adecuado para esa FK en particular...

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). No podemos reproducir tu problema porque **no tenemos la definición de la tabla `Departamento`**. Aún así este SQL debería funcionar. ¿Qué error te da?.

Comment: La demostración de que debería funcionar correctamente la tienes en este ejemplo en línea: [https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gMFPozMm7PuSAHMSMcA5gK/0](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gMFPozMm7PuSAHMSMcA5gK/0). Voto el cierre de la pregunta por no poderse reproducir el problema.

Comment: Es al hacer alder table lo que no me funciona

Comment: Por favor, dinos el mensaje exacto. Un "no me funciona" no nos ayuda a solucionarte el problema.

Comment: Este es mi fallo 

Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`empresa`.`#sql-2678_4`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-2678_4_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Jefe`) REFERENCES `empleados` (`ID_Empleado`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

Comment: Vale, eso es debido a que ya tienes datos en la tabla y hay registros que no tienen un valor de `ID_Jefe` válido. Deberás arreglar esos registros antes de continuar.

Comment: @user161806 , ¿pudiste comprobar las respuestas que te dimos y ver si alguna satisface tus dudas o arregla tu problema?

Answer (score 2):

El problema que estás sufriendo es debido a que tienes datos en la tabla y éstos no cumplen la restricción que intentas agregar.

Pongamos el siguiente ejemplo ([ver en línea](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gMFPozMm7PuSAHMSMcA5gK/1)):

```
INSERT INTO Empleados (
  ID_Empleado, ID_Jefe, Codigo_de_departamento
) VALUES (
  1, NULL, 'Departamento 1'
), (
  2, 1, 'Departamento 1'
), (
  3, 77, 'Departamento 1'
);
```

Un valor `NULL` está permitido, pero el valor de `ID_Jefe=77` generará un error al intentar agregar la relación debido a que no existe ningún registro en la tabla `Empleados` cuya `ID_Empleado` sea `77`. Generará el siguiente error:

> Error: ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`` `test`.`#sql-11d6_4`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-11d6_4_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Jefe`) REFERENCES `Empleados` (`ID_Empleado`) ON DELETE CASCADE ``)

Para solucionarlo debes modificar los valores que no son válidos antes de agregar la relación:

```
UPDATE Empleados
LEFT JOIN Empleados e
  ON e.ID_Empleado = Empleados.ID_Jefe
SET Empleados.ID_Jefe = e.ID_Empleado;
```

Con esta consulta se actualizarán todos los campos `ID_Jefe` con el valor de la unión con la misma tabla mediante un `LEFT JOIN`, que generará un valor `NULL` en el campo `e.ID_Empleado` si la relación no existe.

Tras este arreglo ya no existirá ningún registro que no cumpla la relación que deseas agregar, por lo que podrás agregarla sin problema.

PD: Tal y como sugiere [A. Cedano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/29967/a-cedano) en [su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/336207/18608), deberías cambiar el tipo de acción ante un borrado para no eliminar todos los empleados que tuvieran como jefe al registro que has borrado si usas `ON DELETE CASCADE`, si no que le asigne `NULL` en dicho campo para indicar que se han quedado sin él con un `ON DELETE SET NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Este tipo de llave foránea se conoce como [*self referential*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-adding):

> The foreign key can be self referential (referring to the same table).
>   When you add a foreign key constraint to a table using `ALTER TABLE`,
>   remember to first create an index on the column(s) referenced by the
>   foreign key.

---

> La clave externa puede ser autorreferencial (refiriéndose a la misma tabla). Cuando agrega una restricción de clave foránea a una
>   tabla usando `ALTER TABLE`, recuerde crear primero un índice en las
>   columnas a las que hace referencia la clave foránea.

El error que estás teniendo es porque, para crear esta restricción no puede haber registros huérfanos, es decir, **todos los `ID_Jefe` deben existir como `ID_Empleado`**.

Veamos varios escenarios basados en una versión simplificada de tu tabla:

### Satisface la restricción

```
CREATE TABLE Empleados(
    ID_Empleado VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    ID_Jefe VARCHAR(30),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID_Empleado)
);


INSERT INTO Empleados VALUES ('1','1');
INSERT INTO Empleados VALUES ('2','1');
INSERT INTO Empleados VALUES ('3','2');

ALTER TABLE Empleados
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ID_Jefe) REFERENCES Empleados (ID_Empleado)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Este código no da error, porque los `ID_Jefe` `1` y `2` **existen también como `ID_Empleado`**.

### NO satisface la restricción

```
CREATE TABLE Empleados(
    ID_Empleado VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    ID_Jefe VARCHAR(30),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID_Empleado)
);


INSERT INTO Empleados VALUES ('1','1');
INSERT INTO Empleados VALUES ('2','1');
INSERT INTO Empleados VALUES ('3','4');

ALTER TABLE Empleados
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ID_Jefe) REFERENCES Empleados (ID_Empleado)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Este código arroja el error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`rextester`.`#sql-4f4_1a4a5`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-4f4_1a4a5_ibfk_1`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Jefe`) REFERENCES `empleados` (`ID_Empleado`) ON
>   DELETE CASCADE)

Porque el `ID_Jefe` igual a `4` **no existe como `ID_Empleado`**.

### Mucho OJO con el `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Ten mucho cuidado con el `ON DELETE CASCADE` que estás intentando poner. **Te va a crear un desastre en la tabla**.

Vamos a ver un ejemplo de hecatombe:

```
CREATE TABLE Empleados(
    ID_Empleado VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    ID_Jefe VARCHAR(30),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID_Empleado)
);


INSERT INTO Empleados VALUES ('1','1');
INSERT INTO Empleados VALUES ('2','1');
INSERT INTO Empleados VALUES ('3','1');
INSERT INTO Empleados VALUES ('4','1');
INSERT INTO Empleados VALUES ('5','1');
INSERT INTO Empleados VALUES ('6','1');
INSERT INTO Empleados VALUES ('7','1');
INSERT INTO Empleados VALUES ('8','2');
INSERT INTO Empleados VALUES ('9','2');


ALTER TABLE Empleados
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ID_Jefe) REFERENCES Empleados (ID_Empleado)
ON DELETE CASCADE;

SELECT * FROM Empleados;
```

Aquí todo perfecto, el `SELECT` nos da nuestros resultados:

```
ID_Empleado      ID_Jefe
--------------------------
      1             1
      2             1
      3             1
      4             1
      5             1
      6             1
      7             1
      8             2
      9             2
```

Pero lamentablemente, despidieron al empleado `2` que era jefe delos empleados `8` y `9`:

```
DELETE FROM Empleados WHERE ID_Empleado=2;
SELECT * FROM Empleados;
```

Debido al `ON DELETE CASCADE`, los empleados `8` y `9` perdieron su trabajo junto a su jefe:

```
ID_Empleado      ID_Jefe
--------------------------
      1             1
      3             1
      4             1
      5             1
      6             1
      7             1
```

Quizá el tipo de restricción correcta sea este:

```
ALTER TABLE Empleados
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ID_Jefe) REFERENCES Empleados (ID_Empleado)
ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

Así, cuando despidan al empleado `2`, los empleados `8` y `9` no perderán su trabajo junto con su jefe:

```
ID_Empleado      ID_Jefe
--------------------------
      1             1
      3             1
      4             1
      5             1
      6             1
      7             1
      8             NULL
      9             NULL
```

Como dato curioso, si dejamos el `ON DELETE CASCADE` y borramos al empleado `1`:

```
DELETE FROM Empleados WHERE ID_Empleado=1;
```

La tabla se queda totalmente en blanco, al menos en las pruebas de rextester. No sé si sea un bug de MySQL. Pero esto acentúa el peligro de poner una restricción definida de ese modo.

Comment: Mi +1 por proponer una acción ante el borrado más adecuada y la cantidad de explicaciones x]. Si complementas tu respuesta con la consulta SQL que propongo para corregir los campos que no satisfacen la clave externa, borro la mía.

Comment: @OscarGarcia las respuestas son complementarias. Lo iba a indicar en un comentario en tu respuesta, pero era demasiado largo, además quise explicar también lo del *self referential* que de hecho es algo que acabo de descubrir. Tu respuesta es muy buena y tiene buena acogida, creo que no debes borrarla, pero sí advertir sobre el peligro del `ON DELETE CASCADE` de forma visible.